# laravel 5 orm - orWhere for relationship does not work properly

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5

I have this code

```
$query->whereHas('filters',function($q) use ($filters) {
     $q->where('filter_id', $filters[0]);

     for($i = 1; $i < count($filters); $i++)
     {
         $q->orWhere('filter_id', $filters[$i]);
     }
});
```

Problem is , When it is search for one filter `( count($filters) == 1 )` , Result is correct and show item in relate with this filter , But when i search by multi filter `( count($filters) > 1 )` , Result is all items in db and its like no search done

What i can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can accomplish the same thing you are trying to do with a `wherein` call.

```
$query->whereHas('filters', function($q) use ($filters){
    $q->whereIn('filter_id',$filters);
});
```